# How do I autocomplete and format brackets in Vim?

Tags: vim

I'm working my way through a Java book and as a result, I find myself typing in a lot of curly braces. Considering that I knew how powerful Vim can be, though being far from an expert, I've looked for ways to let it handle the braces for me. I came across the use of `autocmd`s, and I put the following in my .vimrc:
`autocmd FileType java inoremap <buffer> { {<CR><CR>}<Up><Tab>`. I also tried just a normal `inoremap`, to no avail.

What I have now works for the highest level block. However, when I get to any block deeper, the `<Tab>` doesn't seem to execute. Everything else works as expected. But no matter how deep after that, but the cursor always ends up back at the beginning of the method level. I imagine that it's because I told it to add exactly one tab. How can I make the tab count depend on the depth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have some sort of autoindenting set up:

```
augroup Java
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType java inoremap <buffer> { {<CR>}<C-c>O
augroup END
```

What your version does:

1. insert the opening brace,
2. insert a newline,
3. insert a newline,
4. insert the closing brace,
5. move the cursor up *to column 1*,
6. insert a tab.

You got it right: since you only insert a single tab this can only get you to the first level of indentation.

What my version does:

1. insert the opening brace,
2. insert a newline,
3. insert the closing brace,
4. exit insert mode without triggering autocommands,
5. open a new line above the current line.

`:help O` respects your autoindenting settings so it will enter insert mode at the right indentation level.

Alternatively, you could modify your version like this:

```
augroup Java
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType java inoremap <buffer> { {<CR><CR>}<C-c>S
augroup END
```

Where you leave insert mode on the blank line between the braces and do `:help S` to enter insert mode at the right indentation level.

There are *many* ways to skin that cat.

Comment: I just tried this out with a simple `inoremap` and it worked beautifully. Thanks! Don't know why I didn't think of `O` -- it should have been obvious, being such a basic command.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest letting Vim use its built-in Java mode. If you add

```
source $VIMRUNTIME/vimrc_example.vim
```

to your .vimrc, Vim will pick up a load of useful defaults, including automatic filetype detection and formatting rules. You'll find that opening a .java file will give you most of what you want.

And to anticipate your next question, if the tab width isn't what you want, add something like

```
autocmd FileType java setlocal shiftwidth=4
```

to the end of your .vimrc.